# RadioButtons not displaying

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I am doing an exercise from "Advanced Android Development Course". This code doesn't display `RadioButtons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/my_fragment_color"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   tools:context=".SimpleFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/question_article"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/yes"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_no"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>
```

`RadioButtons` appear when I remove `TextView`. How `TextView` hid those buttons? I tried using also `marginEnd` or weight atributes, but this wasn't a solution.

Comment: make `textview` width `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wrap content for your TextView height and width as shown below.

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_btn_bg_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="question_article"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yes"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_no"
            android:text="no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use the **weight attribute** to allocate a portion of the layout’s space to a view, depending on its weight, and for better responsive UI try to use **ConstraintLayout**. To learn more about ConstraintLayout click [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Answer (score 4):

Your **`TextView`** hight is **`match_parent`** that's why your `RadioButton` is not visible

Try to set **`android:layout_weight="1"`** in your  **`TextView`** it will work

Try this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/my_fragment_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".SimpleFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/question_article"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/yes"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button_no"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In example buttons are next to text, how can I move them to left side?

Comment: @pochmurnik didn't get u can you explain more

Comment: I think I should change TextView width and height to wrap_content than add another attribute.

Comment: TextView took whole fragment, I just changed match_parent to wrap_content.

Comment: @pochmurnik you need to set weight as per your requirement if you want to add more views in layout

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:text="@string/question_article"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/yes"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_no"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `LinearLayout` is `orientation="horizontal"`yet your first `TextView` takes full width with `layout_width="match_parent"` leaving no space for any other view.

Review your layout. I'm not sure if you wanted the `TextView` vertically above `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 1):

This property assignment for `textView` is incorrect

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Assign `wrap_content` instead and it will work.